# Custom Slider - MinimumTrackImage is stratched

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8, uislider

I have customized `UISlider` in one of my applications. Here is my code for the slider:

```
UISlider  *slider  = [[UISlider alloc] init];
slider.value = 0;
slider.minimumValue = -12.0f;
slider.maximumValue = 12.0f;
slider.transform =  CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI/2);
slider .frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 150,300);
[slider  setMinimumTrackImage:[UIImage imageNamed:IMAGENEAMED]  forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [slider  setMaximumTrackImage:[UIImage imageNamed:IMAGENEAMED]forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

But `MinimumTrackImage` is **stretched**. Here is the screen shot of the application:

[image]

The Right-hand side slider's image is prefect. When the slider's value is lower then the maximum value, then the image is stretched.

Anyone can help to make the MinimumTrackImage perfect.

Comment: will you try with stretchable image for manimum track image?

Comment: @chiragshah can you please explain more?

Comment: in uislider you can take normal image for this you have to take stretchable image.for more detail please used this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7644296/customizing-slider-track-images?rq=1

Comment: I have tried it. But not working for me.